# Summ a Attribut from Points in a Polygon as Anotation in QGIS

Tags: sql, count, qgis, point-in-polygon

I need a "LIFE" Annotation when end of digitizing a Polygon.  I neend not the Summ of Points like this (array_length(overlay_contains('zensus_c40a84ba_3850_4f60_b02a_1df14041d205', $id))). This way or by trigger on the geopackage? [Cont Points by QGIS Annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnn0y.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum-funktion past version 3.2.0 ?

This in the polygonlayer.
array_sum(overlay_contains('point_layer', pointlayer_atttrb))

pointlayer_atttrb as a Integer!